# данные в базовый шаблон base.html

Tags: python, django

Как можно передать данные в базовый шаблон base.html? ,Вроде бы все перепробовал, наследование не срабатывает, урлом не привяжешь насколько я понимаю.
Есть такой views:

```
  def article_list(request):
      arts = Article.objects.order_by('-added_date')[:3]
      return render(request, 'article/article_list.html', {'arts': arts})
```

base.html

```
 <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6">
           <div class="portfolioInfo__item">
            <h3 class="portfolioInfo__header">RECENT POSTS</h3>
             {% for article in arts %}
              <div class="portfolioInfo__posts">
                <div class="portfolioInfo__posts__item">
                  <div class="portfolioInfo__posts__imgBody">
                    <img scr="{{article.image |thumbnail_url:'article'}}" alt='photo'>
                  </div>
                  <h3 class="portfolioInfo__posts__header">{{article.title}}</h3>
                  <p class="portfolioInfo__posts__detail">{{article.added_date}}</p>
                </div>
              </div>
             {% endfor %}
              <a href="#" class="portfolioInfo__linkTwo">
              <i class="ico-arrow-forward portfolioInfo__linkTwo-prev"></i> 
              Read More Posts
              <i class="ico-arrow-forward portfolioInfo__linkTwo-next"></i>
              </a>
           </div>
        </div>
```

article_list.html

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% load staticfiles thumbnail %}

{% block title %} Blog {% endblock %}

{% block content %}
<header class="headerTwo headerTwo-bgThree">
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12 text-xs-center">
            <h2 class="headerTwo__header">Blog</h2>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

```
<section class="blog">
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12">
            <div class="section__header">
                <h2 class="section__header__text">from the blog</h2>
                <div class="section__header__line">
                    <i class="section__header__line__ico ico-pencil2"></i>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        {% for article in articles %}
        <div class="col-xs-12 blog__item">
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="blog__imgBody">
                    <a href="img/blog4.jpg" class="blog__imgLink">
                        <img src="{{ article.image|thumbnail_url:'article' }}" alt="{{ article.title }}" class="blog__img">
                    </a>
                    <div class="blog__imgControls">
                        <a href="#" class="blog__imgControls__item blog__imgControls__item-black">
                            <i class="ico-link3"></i>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <h3 class="blog__header">{{ article.title }}</h3>
                <div class="blog__tags">
                    <a href="#" class="blog__tag">
                        <i class="ico-image4"></i>
                        Image
                    </a>
                    <a href="#" class="blog__tag">
                        <i class="ico-clock7"></i>
                        {{ article.added_date }}
                    </a>
                    <!--
                    <a href="#" class="blog__tag"><i class="ico-folder-open-o"></i>Photography</a>
                    <a href="#" class="blog__tag"><i class="ico-user5"></i>John Doe</a>
                    <a href="#" class="blog__tag"><i class="ico-comment-o"></i>65</a>
                    -->
                </div>
                <p class="blog__desc">{{article.short_description|safe}}</p>
                <a href="{{ article.slug }}" class="project__share__link">
                    <i class="project__share__link__icoPrev ico-angle-right"></i>
                    <span class="project__share__link__text">Details</span>
                    <i class="project__share__link__icoNext ico-angle-right"></i>
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
        {% endfor %}
    </div>
</div>
```

{% endblock %}

Comment: `arts` не доступен в базовом шаблоне ?

Comment: нет, не доступен

Comment: прикрепите пожалуйста шаблон к вопросу

Comment: С таким кодом он должен быть отлично доступен в любых подключенных шаблонах, давайте больше подробностей

Comment: не видно в `article_list.html` подключение к базовому шаблону `{% extends "base.html" %}`

Comment: все есть, не полностью скопирован файл